# How to make a tkinter Label background transparent?

Tags: python, colors, tkinter, label, transparent

I have a window with a label as my frame. I did this because i wanted an image in the  background. But now im having trouble with the other labels i have used. The other labels i have used to actually labeled things dont have a transparent background. Is there a way to make the background of these labels transparent?

```python
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('background image')

image1 = Tk.PhotoImage(file='image_name.gif')

# get the image size
w = image1.width()
h = image1.height()

# make the root window the size of the image
root.geometry("%dx%d" % (w, h))

# root has no image argument, so use a label as a panel
panel1 = tk.Label(root, image=image1)
panel1.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')

# put a button/label on the image panel to test it
label1 = tk.Label(panel1, text='here i am')
label1.pack(side=Top)

button2 = tk.Button(panel1, text='button2')
button2.pack(side='top')

# start the event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not supported with transparent backgrounds in Tk.

Answer (score 9):

i think it can help, all black will be  transparent

```
root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','black')
```

Comment: Use `root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', root['bg'])` to make the default color transparent.

Comment: This would be a great solution if it only made the colored widget transparent, but it seems to make the colored widget and all lower widgets transparent. If you could make a lifted widget transparent and see the widgets lower than it, that would be great. Any idea how to make that happen?

Comment: Well this works like a charm making a specific color transparent but there are 2 major problems: a) Like Gary02127 said it makes all widgets transparent but not that it seems like (at least on Windows 10) it also makes all areas with the specified color permable too.

Comment: This doesn't work. I have tried it, and it does not accept `-transparentcolor` as a first parameter.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with images and putting text onto them, the most convenient way is - I think - utilizing `Canvas` widget.

`tkinter Canvas` widget has methods as `.create_image(x, y, image=image, options)` and `.create_text(x, y, text="Some text", options)`.

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
from tkinter import *

main=Tk()
photo=PhotoImage(file='test.png')
Label(main,image=photo,bg='grey').pack()
#your other label or button or ...
main.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", 'grey')
main.mainloop()
```

this work if use `bg='grey'` you can change it in line 7

good luck :)

Comment: _tkinter.TclError: bad attribute "-transparentcolor": must be -alpha, -fullscreen, -modified, -notify, -titlepath, -topmost, or -transparent

not working

Comment: This is interesting, but it cut a hole in the entire app with the desktop visible behind the window.

Comment: It worked for me, but the problem is that a pixelated grey outline appears around the text or image for some reason

Comment: @5alidshammout That's due to the antialiased pixels not being the transparency color.