# How can you set a python tkinter widget's background to be transparent in Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make a drag and drop interface for my chess game in tkinter but for this the background of the tkinter widget has to be transparent. How can I achieve this? I know that you can use `root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "somecolour")` to make the background fully transparent. However, in my case this means that you can see past the board and outside of tkinter. What I want is to be able to see the colours of the chess board behind the piece when I am moving it.

Comment: this might help -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814937/tkinter-transparency-on-label

Comment: Related: [Draggable Tkinter Label With Transparent Image Still Covers Image from Parent Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327765/draggable-tkinter-label-with-transparent-image-still-covers-image-from-parent-ca)