# How to make the font more clearly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I make a function to make my GUI app transparent.Here is the code:

```
MyWin.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', 'white') # make the white color transparent.
```

if not transparent:

[image]

Now it can be transparent,and likes this:
[image]

But every words are looked strange.(it look like the config of widget `relief="raised"`).

Is it possible to make it more normal?(it seems that those characters are surrounded by some white pixels,I try to change the font color,but it didn't solve my problem.)

Comment: "**I make a function to make my GUI app transparent**".  Could you show the code for this function?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco The answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461045/python-tkinter-label-background-transparent

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code you are currently using

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I think it maybe doesn't have the connection with the problem.Whatever,I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think you can get much further here with Tkinter.

It looks like Tkinter's implementation of window transparency is "let's call all pixels of this color transparent". Since your text (all text unless you can especially somehow manage to make it not be so) is rendered antialiased, their edges have greyscale (in fact colored, thanks to sub-pixel antialising) pixels:

[image: Zoomed in]

If you now replace all white pixels with a nice backdrop, you get the effect you're seeing:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Now it is okay,I change the font family.Although those characters are still surrounded by some white pixels.But now it looks better.Thanks AKX.

[image]