# Tkinter - Looking for a way to have no labels background

Tags: image, tkinter, background, label, transparent

I'm looking for a way to have no background on my labels, in order to get the main window background (which is an image) sharing with the background of my labels and buttons.
Any idea ?

Thanks, in advance

EDIT : [I want to make the black part of this label the part of the image that is supposed to be behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSUio.png)

EDIT 2 :[There are also buttons and the maze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVWGN.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Tkinter Label background transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461045/python-tkinter-label-background-transparent)

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! However it's not about making it completely transparent, just share the background with the main background

Comment: What do you mean by share the main background? Isn't that what transparent background is? Removing the background so you can just see the letters over the image without the black background?

Comment: "Removing the background so you can just see the letters over the image without the black background?" yes exactly but the thing is I don't only have text I also have a maze constructed with images that has a black background too, and buttons too

Comment: You can use `Canvas` to show the background image with transparent text using `create_image()` and `create_text()`.  But there is still no way to make a button transparent.