# Image background black

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-photoimage

So even though I tried to set the background to custom color the picture is automatically set with bg=black. Witch I am guessing is default.
Can someone tell me in what moment I have to set the background, and how to do it so the picture doesn't get automatically filled with black.

```
window = Tk()
window.title('Random Password Generator')
window.geometry('400x250')
window.config(bg=GREEN)

#openImage
pic = Image.open('lock.png')
#resized
resized = pic.resize((100,150), resample=1)
new_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
#enter image
image = Label(image=new_pic)
image.config(compound='bottom', anchor='e')
image.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10)
```

[image: This is the result at the moment]
[image: This is how it looks in the program (imagine the gray is a white and gray chess board)]

1. why is the picture still bg='black' even though I set it to GREEN

Comment: Even the image has transparent background, but the label does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10461175/4926757), Tkinter labels do not support transparency.

As an alternative, we may create green image, and apply [alpha_composite](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.alpha_composite):

- Create green image with RGBA color format:

  ```
   green_bk = Image.new(mode="RGBA", size=(100, 150), color=(0, 128, 0, 255))
  ```
- Apply alpha composition of resized image and green background:

  ```
  resized_bk = Image.alpha_composite(green_bk, resized)
  ```

---

Code sample:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Random Password Generator')
window.geometry('400x250')
window.config(bg='GREEN')

pic = Image.open('lock.png') # openImage

resized = pic.resize((100,150), resample=1)  # resized

# Green color of Tkinter is (0, 128, 0) https://www.plus2net.com/python/tkinter-colors.php
green_bk = Image.new(mode="RGBA", size=(100, 150), color=(0, 128, 0, 255))  # Create green image with opaque background

resized_bk = Image.alpha_composite(green_bk, resized)  # Apply alpha composition of resized image and green background

new_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_bk)  # Used resized_bk instead of resized
#enter image
image = tk.Label(image=new_pic)
image.config(compound='bottom', anchor='e')
image.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10)

window.mainloop()
```

---

For testing I used the following `lock.png` image (the lock is transparent):
[image]

Tkinter output window:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

This image is filled with black even if its not on a black background.
You should try to set a white bg or just pick an image witch is filled in white